# Procedure copy performs faster than original

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing an intriguing situation with a Oracle database.

A stored procedure is exhibiting a significantly high execution time, and I am exploring ways to optimize it. To test on the production database with minimal risk of impact, I created a copy of this procedure for optimization purposes. However, before making any modifications to the procedure, I noticed that its execution time, with the same parameters, is much faster compared to the original procedure. To emphasize: nothing was changed, only a copy was created.

I attempted to recreate the original procedure, but the sluggish performance persists.

I lack in-depth knowledge of how a procedure is compiled and executed in the database to formulate any hypothesis.

What could be the possible explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: If every thing remains the same except the Procedure name when you are Creating a copy of a procedure and executing then it should not see any changes in performance,, unless you are executing it in a different Database or schema, could you please give us more details with a little sample code.

Comment: You will need to use monitoring tools to determine what it's spending its time on and drill down analytically rather than speculating on what could be different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears be an error in the library cache. Have you tried restarting the database?

Comment: I didn't restart the database, but I executed a command to clear the cache (the database is on RDS): `RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL.FLUSH_SHARED_POOL()` and `RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL.FLUSH_BUFFER_CACHE()`. The issue has been "resolved", at least for now.

I don't understand why this thread was closed, and I would appreciate the opinions of other developers on what might have happened.  I need to understand better what happened to prevent this problem from recurring.